# Qt 5.7 for android: file NOT found for import android.app.Activity in QtActivity.java

Tags: java, android, qt, qt5

I've installed Qt 5.7 for Android and iOS on my Mac Mini.

After installing Java SDK, Android SDK, Android NDK and ANT, I created a "hello world" project and it shows:

> src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity.java:39: error:
>   �޷����� android.app.Activity

I checked line 39 in the generated QtActivity.java file, it is:

> import android.app.Activity

I suspected it to be a path issue. There seems to be nothing wrong with the path settings (Please click the image link below):

See 1,2,3 and 4 for the paths:

[image: See 1,2,3 and 4 for the paths]

I checked position 1,2,3 and 4 and was quite sure that the folders really existed.

I also checked the previous answers on the similar problem in stackoverflow ---- most of them pointed to a "path" issue (incorrect SDK/NDK paths, etc.)

============ Update ==================

I solved this problem.

Actually it's because the java and javc version.

In console, type

> java -version

and

> javac -version

to find out whether the two numbers are same.

Also, if you installed many versions of java (1.6, 1.7 and 1.8), please check (1) in the image to make sure you are using the correct JDK number. In my case, the (1) shows the path of java 1.6, but actually I'm using java/javac ver1.7 (and then I upgraded them to v1.8). That casued the problem.